# Could not connect to the debugger

Tags: c#, monodevelop

Во время начала выполнения программы появляется окно

> Could not connect to the debugger.

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Дайте больше информации. Какой код вызывает сообщение, какая у Вас система и т.д.

Comment: Код - любой. Система Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Код, всмысле консольный. Графический работает.